# Time range option in shutdown for a user in sudoers

Tags: linux, sudo, wildcards

I need to give sudo privileges to a user for shutdown permissions. But the user can only send out a shutdown request with a time of greater than 3 hours. I've been trying by implementing globbing.

For example :

```
username ALL=/usr/sbin/shutdown +[[:digit:]] -> Trial for any number 
username ALL=/usr/sbin/shutdown +[180-*] -> Trial for 180 minutes and beyond
```

And numerous other cases, but nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was a wrapper script in which you grant sudo access to that script and then do the parameter-checking in that script.

```
username ALL=/usr/local/sbin/shutdown-wrapper
```

And then something like this for the shutdown-wrapper:

```
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in
  *[!0-9]*) echo Invalid; exit 2;;
esac

if [ "$1" -ge 180 ]
then
  /usr/sbin/shutdown +"$1"
else
  echo Invalid
  exit 2
fi
```

... and instruct the user to call `sudo /usr/local/sbin/shutdown-wrapper N` where N is the number of minutes.

Another  option is to spell out, using character ranges in from the [Wildcards section of the sudoers man page](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html#Wildcards):

```
username ALL=(ALL:ALL) /usr/sbin/shutdown +18[0-9], \
                       /usr/sbin/shutdown +19[0-9], \
                       /usr/sbin/shutdown +[2-9][0-9][0-9], \
                       /usr/sbin/shutdown +[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*
```

This spells out minutes 180 through 189, 190 through 199, 200 through 999, and then anything (numeric or otherwise!) that starts with at least 4 digits, the first of which cannot be zero. This would allow invalid time ranges, such as `/usr/sbin/shutdown +9999jeff`, which would simply result in a parse error from `shutdown`:

> Failed to parse time specification: +9999jeff

Comment: Wouldn't the last char range as given allow for  `/usr/sbin/shutdown +0000`?

Comment: Well spotted, @RudiC! I've adjusted the wildcard so that the 4+digit number cannot start with zero. Thank you!